# Receiver class does not define an implementation of the resolved method abstract of interface org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, java-11, xsp

I'm receiving this error when I'm trying to start my application with java 11

`Task :SpringBootVPSApplication.main()`
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class com.comcast.xsp.test.integration.XspTestApplicationRunListener does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract starting()V of interface org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener.`
`at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)`
`at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)`
`at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)`
`at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)`
`at com.comcast.xsp.boot.XspApplication.run(XspApplication.java:25)`
`at com.comcast.provisioning.vps.voiceservice.SpringBootVPSApplication.main(SpringBootVPSApplication.java:17)`

> Task :SpringBootVPSApplication.main() FAILED

The application was working fine when I started with java 8, but when I upgraded my xsp boot from 3.3 to 4.5 .It is giving me this error.